# Remove button (not hide) if value being updated already exists

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This code updates a database table to `approved`, regardless of the current database value. I need the form HTML code below the PHP code here to be executed only if the value being updated is not "approved" meaning the button should only display if the value is anything else but `approved`. I don't want the users to see the button for updating the value to `approved` when the value `approved` already exists.
I know how to wrap the code inside an if condition but I don't know what condition to supply given I'm using $wpdb->update.

```
global $wpdb;
$msg = '';
if(isset($_POST['actionp'.$appointment['id']])){
$wpdb->update (

'wp_bkntc_appointment_customers',

 array('status' => 'approved' ),

 array ('appointment_id' => $appointment['id'])

);
$msg ='Update Successful';
}

$pick_shift = 'actionp'.$appointment['id'];

return '<div class="d-flex align-items-center">'.$customersTxt.'<br><form action=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=booknetic&module=appointments method="POST" style="width:100%; white-space: nowrap;">
<input type="submit" style="background:green; color:#fff; border-radius:10px;" onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure you want to PICK the shift?");\' name="'.$pick_shift.'" class="pckbutton" value="Pick" /></form></div>';
```

Something like

```
if (value == "approved") {
   return 'Already Approved';
} elseif {
return '<div class="d-flex align-items-center">'.$customersTxt.'<br>
<form action=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=booknetic&module=appointments 
method="POST" style="width:100%; white-space: nowrap;">
<input type="submit" style="background:green; color:#fff; border-radius:10px;" 
onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure you want to PICK the shift?");\' 
name="'.$pick_shift.'" class="pckbutton" value="Pick" /></form></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a new select query `where id = ??`
or if you are in the same page use:

```
global $wpdb;
$msg = '';
$value = '';
if(isset(...)){
{
    ...
    $value = 'approved';
}
```

at the end:

```
if ($value == "approved") {
   return 'Already Approved';
} else {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm in the same page. I'm a little confused by the if(isset(...)){... $value = 'approved'}. I tried this ```if(isset($_POST[$appointment['status']])="approved")``` but it did not work. I understand the second part just a little not completely sure about what needs to be wrapped in the first section of the code you gave.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['actionp'.$appointment['id']]))` the same as your condition, update then set `$value="approved";`

Comment: The code now works. But I am not sure why the content inside the if...else statement is disappearing immediately after page load. If I use simple ```$test = 1; if ($test==1) {..the output here doesn't dissappear}``` while ```$test = 1; if ($test==1) {..this disappears after page load}``` It disappears when I use the ```$value = '';``` variable as explained in the code. Almost worked just not sure why the strange behavior.